# Creating user specific form access permissions / validation in django admin

Tags: python, django, authentication, permissions, django-admin

I'm using a 'Task' Model to create operations/administrative tasks in my dashboard. Each task has an assignee, and a reviewer. The assignee completes the task by passing several checks, and the reviewer verifies their work, both of these require each user to edit a check, but neither user should be able to access or modify the other's result.

If the assignee views the Task (with checks inline), they should only be able to modify the "result" and "comment" elements of the check, where as the reviewer can only edit the "review_result" and "reviewer_comment" elements.

To validate this I need to use the fact that given a `check`, the current user editing the page is equal to `check.task.assignee` or `check.task.reviewer`.

I cannot find a simple way to do this, even using [django-guardian](https://github.com/django-guardian/django-guardian), as this requires field-level permissions, rather than object level. I considered using modelForm validation, but cannot find a way to access the user from within the model with some hacks such as [django-cuser](https://pypi.org/project/django-cuser/).

Is there another architecture which would allow this? The only way forward that I can see is to use django-guardian combined with two checks, a check and a checkReview, and set object level permissions as the assignee and reviewer are chosen.

```
class Task(PolymorphicModel):
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_created=True)
    date_accepted = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    date_reviewed = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    date_closed = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    state = FSMField(default="open")

    assignee = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=True,
        related_name="assigned_tasks",
        related_query_name="assigned_task",
    )
    reviewer = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=True,
        related_name="review_tasks",
        related_query_name="review_task",
    )

class Check(PolymorphicModel):
    result = models.BooleanField(null=True)
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    review_result = models.BooleanField(null=True)
    reviewer_comment = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)
    task = models.ForeignKey(Task, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct method to achieve this is to override the `get_readonly_fields` method of InlineModelAdmin (In your Inline class).

```
def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None):
    if obj is None:
        logger.error("An admin has created a check from the dashboard (this should not happen)!")
        return []
    user = request.user
    fields = [field.name for field in self.opts.local_fields]
    if user == obj.assignee:
        fields.remove(['result', 'comment'])
    elif user == obj.reviewer:
        fields.remove(['review_result', 'reviewer_comment'])
    return fields
```